# Attached script that uses RayCast to an empty game object and now it's not working, why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I want to shoot a raycast out of the tip of enemies gun and see if it hits the player. To do this I created an empty game object placed inside of the gun in the hierachy and moved the empty game object which I called `TipOfGun` not I attached script to `TipOfGun` called `Gun` with rayCast but it does nothing as far as I'm concerned and after all the testing I've done. I can't figure out why raycast never hits anything. Below is my code and i'm also posting a picture of my hierarchy.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{

    private ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
    Vector3 tipOfGun = new Vector3(0.009f, 0.329f, 0.017f);

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject muzzleFlashObj = GameObject.Find("muzzleFlash");
        muzzleFlash = muzzleFlashObj.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    }



    public void ShootWeapon()
    {

        muzzleFlash.Play();
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, 0.75f, out hit))
        {
            Debug.Log("Name of component hit:" + hit.collider.gameObject.name);

            GameObject hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
            if (hitObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>())
            {
                muzzleFlash.Play();
            }
            else
                muzzleFlash.Stop();
        }

    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Physics.Spherecast` which isn't what you are looking for.
From your description I think you should use `Physics.Raycast`

Try something like this instead of Spherecast:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
```

Give it a try.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: I found out the actual reason why  raycast never hit player. TipoGun wasn't rotated to point at the front of the gun.

Answer (score 0):

After breaking my head a few hours in between days I decided to see if I can see the actual Raycast to determine why it was not hitting my player. I should've thought of this way before for those of you that run into a similar problem you can always draw the actual ray and view it in the scene, with something similar to this.

```
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
Debug.Log("Did Hit");
```